# Trouble with public/protected/private inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance, protected, private-members

I'm attempting a simple example of inheritance in C++. But I just can't get it down. When I try to get the protected members of class `B` inherited from class `A` it says that `A::baz` is protected.

```
#include <iostream>

class A {
    public:
        int foo;
        int bar;
    protected:
        int baz;
        int buzz;
    private:
        int privfoo;
        int privbar;
};

class B : protected A {}; // protected members go to class B, right?

int main() {
    B b;

    b.baz; // here is the error [A::baz is protected]
}
```

I can't seem to find what I'm doing wrong. I've tried changing `class B : protected A` to `: public A` but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Its rare to use anything other than public inheritance.

Comment: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/access-rules-with-priv-inherit.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Protected inheritance just impacts how clients of your class see the **public** interface of the base class. Protected inheritance marks the public members of the base class as protected for users of your inherited class.

So `baz` in your example is not public, it is protected from B, hence the compiler error.

Comment: What if I didn't use either `public`, `private`, or `protected` and just did: `class B : A {}`??

Comment: @user6607 Then it is private by default

Answer (score 2):

You can access `protected` members from *inside* a deriving class, not outside.

```
class B : protected A 
{
   void foo() 
   {
       int x = foo; //ok
       x = baz;     //ok
       x = privfoo; //error
   }
};
```

Inheritance type only limits base class access. If, for example, you choose `protected` inheritance, all `public` methods in `A` will become `protected` to the outside, and the rest remain the same.

Answer (score 0):

protected fields can only be accessed by methods in the class declaring them, or classes inheriting from the declaring class. you are trying to access a protected field ffrom a global function.

Answer (score 0):

Because `A::baz` is protected, `B` can access it:

```
class B : public A
{
  public:
    int some_other_method()
    {
        return baz;
    }
};
```

but that doesn't let other code access it.

Answer (score 0):

> The protected access specifier is similar to private. Its only
>   difference occurs in fact with inheritance. When a class inherits from
>   another one, the members of the derived class can access the protected
>   members inherited from the base class, but not its private members.

More on it [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/inheritance/)

Answer (score 0):

When a member is `protected`, it can only be accessed from within methods of the class that defines it and its descendants.

What you are trying to do is access the `protected/private` members from code external to these classes, which is not allowed. You can only access `public` members of a class from outside of class's scope.

Answer (score 0):

You should read about public/private inheritance in C++.  What you want to achieve is done by replacing

```
class B : protected A {};
```

by

```
class B : public A {};
```

EDIT: I read too fast and didn't notice you tried to access `baz` from main.  You can only access it from a member method.